# How to include x86-mingw32 binaries when install a gem

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

On Windows 7, with ruby 2.1.6:
I try to install gtk3 with:
gem install gtk3

```
C:\>gem install gtk3                                                                                      
Fetching: pkg-config-1.1.6.gem (100%)                                                                     
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.1.6                                                                   
Fetching: cairo-1.14.1-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                             
Successfully installed cairo-1.14.1-x86-mingw32                                                           
Fetching: glib2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                              
Successfully installed glib2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                            
Fetching: gobject-introspection-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                              
Successfully installed gobject-introspection-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                            
Fetching: gio2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                               
Successfully installed gio2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                             
Fetching: atk-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                                
Successfully installed atk-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                              
Fetching: pango-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                              
Successfully installed pango-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                            
Fetching: gdk_pixbuf2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                        
Successfully installed gdk_pixbuf2-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                      
Fetching: cairo-gobject-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                      
Successfully installed cairo-gobject-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                    
Fetching: gdk3-2.2.5-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)                                                               
Successfully installed gdk3-2.2.5-x86-mingw32                                                             
Fetching: gtk3-2.2.5.gem (100%)                                                                           
ERROR:  Error installing gtk3:                                                                            
        The 'gtk3' native gem requires installed build tools.
```

So now I notice that for all the gems it is installing, it gets a version with -x86-mingw32 as part of it. Except for gtk3, it says: gtk3-2.2.5.gem, without the -x86-mingw32.

So my question: How can I force installer to download the version with -x86-mingw32 ? or the fact that it doesn't, does that mean that there is no such gem.

If not, how can I find what previous version does include the binaries as part of the gem i.e. -x86-mingw32

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that is super weird. It looks like there's a bug in the version that ships with `Ruby 2.1.6` that is causing it to do weird things. Probably related to the `platforms` update in `rubygems 2.3.0`.

Anyway, there is a binary version of `gtk3` available but you have to update `rubygems` Try doing `gem update --system` and install `gtk3` again.

*Note:* You can check the available versions of a gem using the [rubygems](https://rubygems.org) site. Here are the [available `gtk3` versions](https://rubygems.org/gems/gtk3).

Comment: Thanks, that did solve the problem. I updated to rubygems 2.4.8. For another purpose I needed to install gtksourceview2, and ran into the exact same problem (even with 2.4.8)

Comment: [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/gtksourceview2/versions/2.2.5) only lists a `mingw32-x86` binary for `gtksourceview2` version 2.2.3